# Find $ 560^{48} (mod 1001)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve this. I'm unable to use the Euler-Fermat theorem and I don't know how to carry on. Any help?

Comment: Study the answers to that "mother thread". You can either use exponentiation by squaring (explained there in the answers) or possibly apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem using the factorization $1001=7\cdot11\cdot13$. In other words, calculate the remainder modulo $7$, $11$ and $13$. By CRT those remainders determines the answer uniquely. If you haven't covered CRT, then exponentiation by squaring is fast (if you have a pocket calculator capable of integer arithmetic up to six digits or so.

Comment: @Jyrki I'll try that, thanks!!

Comment: $560\equiv0\bmod7, 560\equiv-1\bmod11$, and $560\equiv1\bmod13$; that makes it easy to compute $560^{48}$ to those moduli